# Searching for "eu" location on Careers no longer works

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I think it worked two days ago, but since yesterday the result header is "0 jobs near european union". So the keyword is recognized, but apparently the EU has no member states. Search by countries works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for the bug the report. Searching for EU works again as of a few seconds ago.